# finding the sum of smaller elements on left

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

i came across a problem of finding the number of smaller elements on left of each element in an array of integers, which can be solved in *O(nlgn)* by using *Binary Indexed trees*(like AVL, etc) or *Merge Sort*. Using an AVL tree one can calculate the size of left sub-tree for each element and this would be the required answer. However I can't come up how to calculate the *sum* of the smaller elements left to each element efficiently. For each element , do i have to traverse the left sub-tree and sum the values at nodes or is there any better way(using Merge Sort etc)?
E.g for the array: `4,7,1,3,2` the required ans would be: `0,4,0,1,1`

Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't the last answer be `1` too? Also, could you describe how would you solve the counting problem using an AVL tree? It's not clear to me.

Comment: thanks..corrected.For counting problem,while adding any element it is compared to root ,if less then add to left else to right. So for any node the size of its left sub-tree would give the number of elements smaller than it.

Comment: Yes, that way you can count the number of items smaller than it. But they won't be limited to the items on the left of it. Oh, maybe now I get it: you count the smaller items right after you insert something, not at the end, right?

Answer (score 2):

In *Binary Indexed trees* you store **the number of child nodes** for every node of the binary search tree. This allows you to find number of nodes, preceding each node (number of smaller elements).

For this task, you can store **the sum of child node values** for every node of the binary search tree. This allows you to find the sum of values for preceding nodes (sum of smaller elements). Also in O(n*log(n)).

Answer (score 2):

Check [this tutorial](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=binaryIndexedTrees) on Binary Indexed Tree. This is a structure, that uses **O(n)** memory and can proceed such tasks:
 1. Change value of a[i] by(to) x, call this `add(i,x)`;
 2. Return sum all of a[i], i<=m, call this `get(x)`.
in **O(log n)**.

Now, how to use this to your task. You can do this in 2 steps.
Step one. Copy, sort and remove duplicates from original array. Now you can remap numbers, so they are in range [1...n].
Step 2. Now walk through the array from left to right. Let A[i] - be the value in original array, new[i] - mapped value. (if A = [2, 7, 11, -3, 7] then new = [2, 3, 4, 1, 2]).

The answer is get(new[i]-1).

Update the values: `add(new[i], 1)` for counting, `add(new[i], A[i])` for sum.

All in all. Sorting and remapping is **O(n logn)**. Working on array is **n * O(log n)** = **O(n log n)**. So total complexity is **O(n logn)**

Alternatively, use [treap](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/algorithm/101818/) (in russian).

**EDIT:** Building new array.
Suppose the original array  A = [2, 7, 11,-3, 7]
Copy it to B and sort, B = [-3, 2, 7, 7, 11]
Do a unique B = [-3, 2, 7, 11].
Now to get new, you can

1. add all of elements to map in increasing order, e.g. (-3 -> 1, 2->2, 7->3, 11->4)
2. for each element in A, do a binary search over B

Comment: for the last '7' how is the position determined? Is it (position of first '7')-1 and will it be calculated similarly if there are more than 2 duplicates?

Comment: If you want to remove duplicates move on array from 2nd element, to end, supporting counter of duplicates. If B[i] == B[i-cnt-1] increase cnt by 1. Else if cnt != 0, swap B[i] and B[i-cnt]. Remove last cnt elements from B. Basically, you want to get **relative** numbers, instead of initial values in order to use BIT.

Comment: For each node, have the sum of keys in its subtree. When merging/splitting do sum(parent) = sum(left) + sum(right) + value. Then when getting a sum of all, less then X do a slice by X, return sum of left tree. Both operations work in O(4 * log N) if priorities are random, so you have O(log N) solution.

Comment: @kilotaras: may be i'm missing out on something very obvious but this is what i've understood..from the mapping, if we do a binary search of each A's element: 2->2, 7->3, 11->4, -3->1 and 7-> ? How do we get '2' again for the 7 so that new array is {2,3,4,1,2}

Comment: The new[i] is 1-based position of A[i] in B. You can find this in 2 ways. Have a map:value -> new value. For each number in A, do a binary search over B, to get its position.

Comment: How do you use positions in the input array in treap-based solution? I don't see how left tree produces smaller elements that are also on the left in the original array.

Comment: You add elements into treap one by one. Initially its empty, or contains +infinity.

Answer (score 1):

The following code has a complexity of O(nlogn).
It uses a binary indexed tree to solve the problem.

```
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

const int MX_RANGE = 100000, MX_SIZE  = 100000;
int tree[MX_RANGE] = {0}, a[MX_SIZE];

int main() {
  int n, mn = MX_RANGE, shift = 0;
  scanf("%d", &n);

  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    if(a[i] < mn) mn = a[i];  
  }

  shift = 1-mn; // we need to remap all values to start from 1

  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    // Read answer
    int sum = 0, idx = a[i]+shift-1;
    while(idx>0) {
      sum += tree[idx];
      idx -= (idx&-idx);
    } 

    printf("%d ", sum);

    // Update tree
    idx = a[i]+shift;
    while(idx<=MX_RANGE) {
      tree[idx] += a[i];
      idx += (idx&-idx);
    }
  }

  printf("\n");
}
```